# How can I get all the emails from people who have messaged me?

Tags: linkedin-api

Looking for an API method in LinkedIn that allows me to GET all the emails from people who have messaged me in the past.
Can't find anything in the docs. Any help is much appreciated

Comment: Have a look at [How i can get my connections email address using linkedin api in iphone application?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/29300329/1364007) - `Justin Kominar` said: "*Please be aware that as of May 12th, 2015, access to connections will no longer be available through the API without specific permission from LinkedIn. See [developer.linkedin.com/blog/posts/2015/…](https://developer.linkedin.com/blog/posts/2015/developer-program-changes) for additional information.*"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

LinkedIn does not provide any publicly available API calls that provide such functionality.  In order for you to achieve this, you would need to apply to become a member of a LinkedIn Partner Program:  https://developer.linkedin.com/partner-programs/apply